# since unity upgrade, OnSceneLoaded not getting called on scene start

Tags: unity, c#

I upgraded my unity project to 2018.3.11f.  Since that upgrade, the `OnSceneLoaded` event is not getting called, even though I am registering the event handler.

Here's the class:

```
public class SceneSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        print("scene loaded: " + scene.name);
    }

    void Start()
    {
        print("SceneSwitcher.Start() called");
        print("adding event handler to SceneManager");
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }
}
```

here's the console output:

```
SceneSwitcher.Start() called
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
SceneSwitcher:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/SceneSwitcher.cs:45)
adding event handler to SceneManager
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
SceneSwitcher:Start() (at Assets/Scripts/SceneSwitcher.cs:46)
```

`scene loaded: 3` is never in the console output.

I see [others have had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781810/onsceneloaded-not-getting-called-on-scene-start), with no answers.

This code worked before the upgrade.  Now I am stuck.  Not sure what I can do.  Any help is appreciated.

Thnx

Comment: perhaps because in the snippet you show, there is no changing of scene request

Comment: I moved the code from Start() to Awake().  Now it works.  It seems like order of events behind the scenes might have changed or something.  I will post this as the answer.  If someone can help me understand why that changed worked, that would be great.  (to verify my change worked, I moved it back to Start() and the sceneloaded event was not called).  Awake() is the correct place for this now.

Comment: @BugFinder fair point. I am switching scenes (and I believe before the upgrade the event was called even during my first scene). I do not know how to "prove" that concisely enough.  If you have a suggestion what else to include, I am happy to add it.

Comment: All i can say is code order is a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your Project Settings (Edit/Project Settings) - under the Editor tab you will find the Enter Play Mode Settings option.

[image]

As long as this option is disabled, or both this and the Reload Scene option are enabled, the sceneLoaded event should be triggered as expected. If you enable Enter Play Mode Options but disable Reload Scene, the editor apparently does not fully "load" the scene which in turn prevents the sceneLoaded event from triggering.

(IIRC disabling this option is one of the recommended settings to speed up switching from editor to play mode but it seems to have unwanted side effects)